# i have diffuculty identifying the Scope of action of LoopWhileDO

Tags: java, loops, apache-camel

I was trying to use loop in apache camel to handle some data got from database in case running out of memory. However, after handle all the data, i need to write them to a file, so I used ".end()" to end the loop and use .to() to anouther route to write to file, but it seems the last step was in the loop as well and it has been wrote to file several times.

```java
from("seda:start")
.loopDoWhile(header("loopflag"))
.to()//handle data
.end()
.to("seda:generateFile");

from("seda:generateFile")
.to(...)
```

Comment: well, now I have bypass the problem by setting the loop part as a single route, use a "parent route" to control steps and therefore .end() will be the last step of the loop route.

Comment: By the way: very good solution! Externalizing capsuled blocks of a route to a subroute keeps your main route clean and much easier to read. And you avoid DSL scope problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

**That should work!** And it worked in a short test I did with Camel 2.17.x. What version of Camel are you using?

Try to **put log statements** inside the loop and after ending the loop to verify that the loop behaves as you describe.

```
from("seda:start")
    .loopDoWhile(header("loopflag"))
        .log("must be logged for every loop cycle")
        .to()//handle data
    .end()
    .log("must only be logged once per input message")
    .to("seda:generateFile");
```

I used a direct endpoint in the `from` and mock endpoints in the `to`s, but that should make no difference.